Using custom N2D machine type for GKE node auto provisioning
I am using GKE 1.29 cluster with cluster autoscaler and node autoprovisioning. As of now I am using the N2D machine type for my GKE workloads, and there I am using the n2d-standard-4 machine type using the following node affinity configurations in my deployments.
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: cloud.google.com/machine-family
                operator: In
                values:
                - n2d
              - key: node.kubernetes.io/instance-type
                operator: In
                values:
                - n2d-standard-4

I want to use a custom machine type with 4 CPUs and 8 GB of memory. How can I get this done using node affinity? I have tried following the configuration, but it didn't work.
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: cloud.google.com/machine-family
                operator: In
                values:
                - n2d
              - key: node.kubernetes.io/instance-type
                operator: In
                values:
                - n2d-custom-4-8192

The above configuration is not creating any node pool at all, and pods are in a pending state.
Am I using the right method for provisioning nodes with custom machine types, or is there any better or right solution for this?
In NAP logs I am getting this with no scale up decision
noScaleUp: {
  unhandledPodGroups: [
    0: {
      napFailureReasons: [
        0: {
          messageId: "no.scale.up.nap.pod.zonal.failing.predicates"
          parameters: [
            0: "us-central1-a"
            1: "node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Node Auto-provisioning supports creating nodes with predefined machine types (like n2d-standard-4) but does not automatically create custom machine types (like n2d-custom-4-8192). If you need custom machine types, you cannot change the machine type of an existing node directly.
Hence, you need to create new node pool to align your affinity rules with the predefined machine types supported by GKE's auto-provisioning.

I don't want to modify existing node pools, but I want node auto-provision to add new node pools with custom machine types based on node affinity or any other way.

As what I mentioned NAP does not automatically create custom machine types n2d-custom-4-8192 you need to create new node pool to align your affinity rules.

Review the deployment/pod’s node affinity to confirm the alignment with the labels on the nodes in the intended cluster, here are the steps:

If accurate then create a new node pool with proper labels as it's not allowed to update existing node pools with new labels. Be mindful of cluster labels and node pool labels naming convention in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) to distinguish labels and avoid this error.

If inaccurate then correct the affinity rule in the pod spec to match the labels of their node pools.




I'm using node auto-provisioning, so I don't create node pools manually. The cluster dynamically creates node pools based on the needs of unscheduled pods. If I were to create a custom node pool, I'd lose this functionality and have to manage node pools manually, which I'd like to avoid.
